# adding char into an array and returning

Tags: c, arrays, char

Im new to c and am trying to understand pointers.
here I am opening a file and reading the lines given. Im trying to append these lines into an array and return it from the function. I dont seem to be appending or accessing the array correctly. output[count] = status; gives an error with mismatched char and char *.

Im essentially trying to get an array with a list of words given by a file where each element in the array is a word.

```
char *fileRead(char *command, char output[255]) {

    int count = 0;
    char input[255];
    char *status;

    FILE *file = fopen(command, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
    } else {
        do {
            status = fgets(input, sizeof(input), file);
            if (status != NULL) {
                printf("%s", status);
                strtok(status, "\n");

                // add values into output array
                output[count] = status;
                ++count;
            }
        } while (status);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return output;
}
```

I access fileRead via:

```
...
        char commandArray[255];
        char output[255];
        int y = 0;
        char *filename = "scriptin.txt";
        strcpy(commandArray, fileRead(filename, output));
        // read from array and pass into flag function
        while (commandArray[y] != NULL) {
            n = flagsfunction(flags, commandArray[y], sizeof(buf), flags.position, &desc, &parentrd, right, left, lconn);
            y++;
...
```

Comment: What output are you getting when you call the function?

Comment: @mattjegan characters given from the file, which are returned as an array of characters.

Comment: Ok, so that's the expected result. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: `output[count] = status;` should give you a warning (at least) because they are different types....

Comment: You cannot assign `status` to `output[count]` (e.g. mismatched `char` and `char *`) You also should not call `strtok` and not make use of its return. If `strtok` fails -- then what?. Please *enable compiler warnings* (e.g. at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` as part of your compile string and do not accept code until it compiles without warning and do not attempt to typecast to eliminate warning (except to `void *`).

Comment: @John3136 yes I initally had output[count] = (char) status; however this is meaningless, I believe my output type is incorrect.

Comment: @mattjegan when attempting to use the variables in the array outside the function, they are gibberish printf("%s", &output[1]); gives me ���

Comment: Using `strtok` just to remove the `\n` is a poor approach.

Comment: @Silverfin show how you call `fileRead`. And also read this: [MCVE].

Comment: @MichaelWalz will do

Comment: @Silverfin what is `commandArray`? Do you expect `commandArray` to contain each line of the file you are reading? (first line in `commandArray[0]`, second line in `commandArray[1]` etc)

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes exactly, each line an element in the array. Each is a command I want my program to run.

Comment: @xing yes, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of Read from file Line by line then storing nonblank lines into an array (array of pointer to `char` (as `char*`))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//for it does not exist because strdup is not a standard function. 
char *strdup(const char *str){
    char *ret = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    if(ret)
        strcpy(ret, str);
    return ret;
}

//Read rows up to 255 rows
int fileRead(const char *filename, char *output[255]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Cannot open file:");
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    char input[255];
    while(count < 255 && fgets(input, sizeof(input), file)) {
        char *line = strtok(input, "\n");
        if(line)//When it is not a blank line
            output[count++] = strdup(line);//Store replica
    }
    fclose(file);

    return count;
}

int main(void){
    char *output[255];//(`char *` x 255)
    int number_of_read_line = fileRead("data.txt", output);

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_read_line; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", output[i]);
        free(output[i]);//Discard after being used
    }

    return 0;
}
```